Não consigo pegar os dados de uma planilha usando find_elemente xpath do Selenium
Caros, bom dia.
Até o dia 17 o script que vou colocar aqui funcionava perfeitamente. A partir de ontem já não funciona mais.
Poderiam me ajudar a encontrar uma correção para o mesmo?
Segue script:
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
tabela = pd.read_excel("Emitir.xlsx")
navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
for i, vendedor in enumerate(tabela["Vendedor"]):
cpf = tabela.loc[i, "CPF"]

cnpj = tabela.loc[i, "CPF / CNPJ"]

telefone = tabela.loc[i, "TELEFONE"]

navegador.get("URL_FORM_DO_GOOGLE")

navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(vendedor)
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(int(cpf))
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(int(cnpj))
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(int(telefone))
navegador.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/span').click()

Abaixo segue o erro apresentado:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.141)
Stacktrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF77380FB05+28789]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF7737786E0]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF773615759]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF773662E64]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF773660F7D]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77368F43A]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77365C5B6]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77368F650]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF7736AF654]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77368F1E3]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77365A938]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77365BAA1]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF773B4933D+3410093]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF773B5E7DD+3497293]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF773B52A73+3448803]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7738D7BBB+848171]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF773783C3F]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77377F6E4]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77377F87D]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF77376ED49]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB6E007374+20]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB6E15CC91+33]

